# Creating new columns based on a pattern

Tags: r, data.table

I have a large dataset which has a pattern similar to the `dataPattern` below. I need help with the code to create the `desiredresult` dataset

```
library(data.table)    

V1 <- rep(c(rep("a", times = 2), letters[2:5], 
                    rep("f", times = 2)), times = 2)


V2 <- c(c(c(0.24, 0.25), 2:5, c(0.95, 1.05)),
               c(c(0.34, 0.35), 2:5, c(1.95, 2.05)) )

(dataPattern <- data.table(V1, V2))

(desiredresult <- data.table(V1, V2, c(rep(c(0.24, 0.25), times = 4),
                             rep(c(0.34, 0.35), times = 4)),
                     c(rep(c(0.95, 1.05), times = 4),
                             rep(c(1.95, 2.05), times = 4))))
```

I need help to create column `V3` in the `desiredresult`. The pattern is as follows:

if `V1 == "a"` then `V3 = V2`
if `V1 != "a"` we repeat the previous corresponding set of `V2` values until a new value of `a` is reached then the new values of `V2` is placed in `V3`, etc. The above repeats for all new values of `a`.

I also need your help with the code to create Column `V4` in the `desiredresult` which is similar to column `V3` except it checks if `V1 == "f"` and places the values of `f` from `V2` into `V4` and repeats it if `V1 != "f"`

I have tried:

```
rle(dataPattern$V1 == "a" )
# Run Length Encoding
  # lengths: int [1:4] 2 6 2 6
  # values : logi [1:4] TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

The sequence where `V1 != "a"` or `V1 != "f"` appears to be equal to the number of `FALSE` minus Number of `TRUE`. This is how many times each `a` sequence need to be repeated until a new `a` is reached

Many Thanks

Comment: Does "f V1 != "a" we repeat the previous set of a values until a new value of a is reached then the new values of V2 is placed in V3" really mean to be "f V1 != "a" we repeat the previous set of V1 values until a new value of a is reached then the new values of V2 is placed in V3"?

Comment: Shawn, here is what I meant:  if  "a" is found in "V1" copy the values of V2 to "V3". If "a" is not found in "V1" repeat the above values of V2 to "V3" until a new value is found in "V1"

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is a better way, I think, to get the values of V2 into the column depending on `V1=='a'`.

```
V1 <- rep(c(rep("a", times = 2), letters[2:5], 
            rep("f", times = 2)), times = 2)

V2 <- c(c(c(0.24, 0.25), 2:5, c(0.95, 1.05)),
        c(c(0.34, 0.35), 2:5, c(1.95, 2.05)) )

dataPattern <- data.frame(V1, V2)
dataPattern$V3 <- ifelse(dataPattern$V1 == "a", dataPattern$V2, NA)
dataPattern$V4 <- ifelse(dataPattern$V1 == "f", dataPattern$V2, NA)
for (i in 1:nrow(dataPattern)){
    if (dataPattern$V1[i] == "a"){
        tmpa <- dataPattern$V3[i]
    }
    if (is.na(dataPattern$V3[i])){
        dataPattern$V3[i] <- tmpa
    }
    if (dataPattern$V1[nrow(dataPattern)-(i-1)] == "f"){
        tmpf <- dataPattern$V4[nrow(dataPattern)-(i-1)]
    }
    if (is.na(dataPattern$V4[nrow(dataPattern)-(i-1)])){
        dataPattern$V4[nrow(dataPattern)-(i-1)] <- tmpf
    }
}
```

output, which I think is more correct, according to your stated rules, than `desiredoutput`:

```
> dataPattern
   V1   V2   V3   V4
1   a 0.24 0.24 0.95
2   a 0.25 0.25 0.95
3   b 2.00 0.25 0.95
4   c 3.00 0.25 0.95
5   d 4.00 0.25 0.95
6   e 5.00 0.25 0.95
7   f 0.95 0.25 0.95
8   f 1.05 0.25 1.05
9   a 0.34 0.34 1.95
10  a 0.35 0.35 1.95
11  b 2.00 0.35 1.95
12  c 3.00 0.35 1.95
13  d 4.00 0.35 1.95
14  e 5.00 0.35 1.95
15  f 1.95 0.35 1.95
16  f 2.05 0.35 2.05
```

Comment: Shawn, this does not produce the "desiredresult" dataset

Comment: Right, explain the `V4` values, again? What happens, for example, to the first values of `V4` until a `V1=='f'` is reached? What is there value? `V4[1:6] alternate between `.95` and `1.05` before those values ever appear in `V1`.

Comment: The exact same thing applies with `V4` as with `V3`, except in opposite order. Whereas `V3` searches for `"a" (V1[1:2])` first and then progresses forward to `V1[3:8]`, `V4` operates in the opposite direction. `V4` searches for `"f" (V1[8:7])` and progresses backwards to `V1[6:1]`.

Comment: I am sorry Shawn, this answer does not do it

Comment: If you want to test for a match with the desired output, maybe use `all.equal`.

Comment: Sorry, @RagyIsaac, I couldn't get back straight to it, I had some RW business to attend to. Here is something updated based on your clarification of V4 requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
dataPattern[, `:=`(
  V3 = head(V2,2), 
  V4 = tail(V2,2)
), by=cumsum( V1 == "a" & shift(V1,type="lead") == "a" )]
```

The result passes the `all.equal(dataPattern, desiredresult)` check. Depending on what your actual use-case looks like, you might need to put something different inside the `cumsum`.